# widget not working when adding another function

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I'm new to Dojo and javascript api of arcgis .I want to develop a webgis using dojo and javascript api. The project uses some widgets like bookmark, measurement. these tools work correctly but when i can't use direction widget when i add to the project.The direction widget is not load properly and i gort the following error

init.js:113 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…) "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How can i fix the problem ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Identify with Popup</title>


<style>
    html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">

<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/MyStyles2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/agsjs/css/agsjs.css" />
<script src="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/init.js"></script>
<script>

var map,toc,tb,queryTask;

var theme = "Wetland";
require(["esri/map","agsjs/dijit/TOC", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend","dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser","esri/dijit/OverviewMap"
            ,"esri/dijit/Scalebar","esri/toolbars/navigation","dijit/registry","dojo/on","esri/tasks/GeometryService","esri/SpatialReference","esri/tasks/ProjectParameters","dojo/dom","esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/layers/ImageParameters","esri/dijit/Geocoder","esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",  "esri/geometry/screenUtils","dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/query","dojo/_base/Color","esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
            ,"esri/InfoTemplate", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/layout/BorderContainer","esri/Color","dojo/keys","esri/config","esri/sniff","esri/SnappingManager", "esri/dijit/Measurement",
            "dojo/dom-construct","dojo/dom-class","esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol","esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol","esri/tasks/IdentifyTask","esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters","esri/dijit/Popup", "dojo/_base/array","dojo/_base/connect","esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol","esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic","esri/toolbars/draw","esri/dijit/InfoWindow","esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer","dojox/charting/Chart2D", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
            "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight", "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip","dojox/charting/themes/" + theme, "dojo/dom-class","dojo/number","esri/geometry/Point","dojo/dom-style",
            "dojo/fx/Toggler","dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/RadioButton","esri/dijit/Bookmarks","esri/dijit/Directions","dojo/ready",
            "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" , "dijit/Toolbar","dijit/TitlePane",
            "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","dojox/layout/FloatingPane","dijit/form/Button" ,"dojo/fx","dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Map,TOC,Tiled,FeatureLayer,Legend, arrayUtils, parser,overviewmap,Scalebar,Navigation,registry,on,GeometryService,SpatialReference,ProjectParameters,dom,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,ImageParameters,Geocoder,Graphic,SimpleMarkerSymbol,
                 screenUtils,domConstruct, query, Color,Search,FeatureLayer,InfoTemplate,AccordionContainer,ContentPane,BorderContainer,esriColor,Keys,esriConfig, has,SnappingManager, Measurement,construct,
                 domClass,SimpleFillSymbol,SimpleLineSymbol,IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters, Popup,arrayUtils,connect,PictureFillSymbol,CartographicLineSymbol,
                 Graphic,Draw,InfoWindow,SimpleRenderer, TabContainer,Chart2D, Pie,Highlight, MoveSlice, Tooltip,dojoxTheme, domClass,number,Point,domstyle,Toggler,CheckBox,RadioButton,Bookmark,Directions,Ready) {


            Ready(function () {
                parser.parse();
                // Close Sidebar - remove draggable Splitter
                function toggleSidebar(appLayout, contentAccordion) {
                    var panelIndex = appLayout.getIndexOfChild(contentAccordion);
                    if (panelIndex >= 0) {
                        appLayout.removeChild(contentAccordion);
                    } else {
                        appLayout.addChild(contentAccordion);
                    }
                }

//Close Sidebar - leave draggable Splitter
                function toggleSidebarWidth(appLayout, contentAccordion) {
                    var size = dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode);
                    if (size.w > 0) {
                        dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode, {w: 0});
                    } else {
                        dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode, {w: 100});
                    }
                    appLayout.resize();
                }

                dojo.ready(function () {

                    var appLayout,
                            contentAccordion,
                            accordionPane1,
                            center,


                    // create the BorderContainer and attach it to our appLayout div
                            appLayout = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({}, dojo.byId("appLayout"));

                    // create the AccordionContainer
                    contentAccordion = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "top",
                        id: "top",
                        splitter: "true",
                        minSize: "0",
                        duration: "125"
                    }, "top");


                    tab1top = new dijit.layout.TabContainer(
                            {
                                attachParent: "true",
                                title: "Draw",
                                tabPosition: "top",
                                tabStrip: "true",
                                id: "tab1top"

                            }, "tab1top");
                    contentAccordion.addChild(tab1top);
                    generaltools = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "General Tools",
                        id: "generaltools"
                    }, 'generaltools');
                    tab1top.addChild(generaltools);


                    /////


                    generaltools2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "Genera2 Tools",
                        id: "generaltools2"
                    }, 'generaltools2');
                    tab1top.addChild(generaltools2);
////

                    // add the AccordionContainer to the BorderContainer
                    appLayout.addChild(contentAccordion);

                    // create the TabContainer
                    center = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "center",
                        id: "center"

                    }, "center");
                    /// rightpane
                    rightpane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "right",
                        id: "right",
                        style: "width:250px"

                    }, "rightpane");
                    appLayout.addChild(rightpane);
                    contentAccordionleft = new dojox.layout.ExpandoPane({
                        region: "left",
                        id: "left",
                        splitter: "true",
                        minSize: "0"
                    }, "left");
                    tab1 = new dijit.layout.TabContainer(
                            {
                                attachParent: "true",
                                tabPosition: "bottom",
                                tabStrip: "true",
                                id: "tab1"

                            }, "tab1");
                    contentAccordionleft.addChild(tab1);
                    appLayout.addChild(contentAccordionleft);
//                        contentAccordion.addChild(accordionPaneleft);
                    contentpanetab1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({

                        title: "legend"
                    }, "contenttab1")
                    // add the TabContainer to the BorderContainer
                    appLayout.addChild(center);

                    // calculate and set layout
                    appLayout.startup();

                    // Add button to Tab 1
                    var button1 = new dijit.form.Button({
                        id: "addremovebtn",
                        style: "position:absolute;top:20px;right:40px;height:36px;",
                        iconClass: 'AddRemove',
                        onClick: function () {
                            toggleSidebar(appLayout, contentAccordion);

                        }
                    }, "AddRemove").placeAt("center", "last");
                    domstyle.set(addremovebtn.domNode, "width", "30px");
                    domstyle.set(addremovebtn.domNode.firstChild, "display", "block");

                });


// toggler to show xy coordinate
                var toggler1 = new Toggler({
                    node: "basicNode1"
                });
                var toggler2 = new Toggler({
                    node: "basicNode2"
                });
//checkbox to check the XY coordinate
                var checkBox = new CheckBox({

                    name: "checkBox",
                    value: "agreed",
                    checked: "true",
                    style: "position: absolute;left:650px;top:35px;",

                    onChange: function () {
                        toggler1.hide(), toggler2.hide();
                        if (dijit.byId("checkBox").checked) {
                            toggler1.show();
                            toggler2.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            toggler1.hide();
                            toggler2.hide();
                        }
                    }


                }, "checkBox").startup();


//toggler to show bookmark


                var togglerbook1 = new Toggler({
                    node: "bookmarknode"
                });

//checkbox to check the XY coordinate
                var BookmarkCheck = new CheckBox({

                    name: "checkboxbook",
                    value: "agreed",
                    checked: "true",
                    style: "position: absolute;left:650px;top:55px;",

                    onChange: function () {
                        togglerbook1.hide()
                        if (dijit.byId("BookmarkCheck").checked) {
                            togglerbook1.show();


                        }
                        else {
                            togglerbook1.hide();

                        }
                    }

                }, "BookmarkCheck").startup();

                domClass.add(dom.byId('mesurementID'));

                // Use the info window instead of the popup.(For Pie Chart)

                var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(null, domConstruct.create("div"));
                infoWindow.startup();
                map = new Map("map", {logo: false, infoWindow: infoWindow});


                //For Pie Chart
                map.infoWindow.resize(275, 275);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate();
                // Flag icons are from http://twitter.com/thefella, released under creative commons.
                template.setTitle("<br>  ${District}منطقه </br>");
                template.setContent(getWindowContent);


                var popup = new Popup({
                    fillSymbol: new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                                    new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))
                }, domConstruct.create("div"));
                var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
                imageParameters.format = "jpeg";
                var tiled = new Tiled("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ol/olbasemap/MapServer");
                var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/layers2/MapServer");
                var traffic = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/na/MapServer");

                var statesLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Stat/MapServer/0", {
                    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                    infoTemplate: template,
                    outFields: ["*"]
                });
                map.addLayers([tiled, dynamicMapServiceLayer, statesLayer, traffic]);

                //Pie chart


                function getWindowContent(graphic) {
                    map.infoWindow.resize(275, 275);
                    // Make a tab container.
                    var tc = new TabContainer({
                        style: "width:100%;height:100%;"
                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));

                    // Display attribute information.
                    var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "Details",
                        content: "سstat" +
                        graphic.attributes.District + "<br>جمعیت کل  : " +
                        graphic.attributes.TotalEdu + "<br>OBJECTID: " +
                        graphic.attributes.OBJECTID


                    });


                    var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "Pie Chart"
                    });
                    tc.addChild(cp1);
                    tc.addChild(cp2);

                    // Create the chart that will display in the second tab.
                    var c = domConstruct.create("div", {
                        id: "demoChart"
                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));
                    var chart = new Chart2D(c);
                    domClass.add(chart, "chart");

                    // Apply a color theme to the chart.
                    chart.setTheme(dojoxTheme);
                    chart.addPlot("default", {
                        type: "Pie",
                        radius: 70,
                        htmlLabels: true
                    });
                    tc.watch("selectedChildWidget", function (name, oldVal, newVal) {
                        if (newVal.title === "Pie Chart") {
                            chart.resize(180, 180);
                        }
                    });

                    // Calculate percent male/female.
                    var total = graphic.attributes.TotalEdu;
                    var educatedman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_EducatedMan / total * 100, 2);
                    var educatedwoman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_EducatedWoman / total * 100, 2);
                    var uneducatedman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_UnEducatedMan / total * 100, 2);
                    var uneducatewodman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_UnEducatedWoman / total * 100, 2);
                    chart.addSeries("PopulationSplit", [{
                        y: educatedman,
                        tooltip: "A",
//                            text: "educatedman"
                    }, {
                        y: educatedwoman,
                        tooltip: "b",
//                            text: "educatedwoman"
                    },
                        {
                            y: uneducatedman,
                            tooltip: "c",
//                                text:"uneducatedman"
                        },
                        {
                            y: uneducatewodman,
                            tooltip: "d",
//                                text: "uneducatewodman"
                        }
                    ]);
                    //highlight the chart and display tooltips when you mouse over a slice.
                    new Highlight(chart, "default");
                    new Tooltip(chart, "default");
                    new MoveSlice(chart, "default");

                    cp2.set("content", chart.node);
                    return tc.domNode;
                }

                var directions = new Directions({
                    map: map,
                    routeTaskUrl: "http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/mobile/traffic_wgs2/NAServer/Route"


                },"dir");
                directions.startup();
            });
        });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

</script>
</head>

<body  class="claro" role="main">
<div id="appLayout"  style="width:100%; height:100%;" >

</div>
<div id="rightpane">

    <div id="dir"></div>
</div>
<div id="center">

    <div id="map" style="background-color:#F7F3E7;width:100%;height:100% ">
        <div id="bookmarknode" style="position:absolute; right:120px; top:20px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">


            <div id="bookmarks-pane"
                 data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane"
                 data-dojo-props="title:'Bookmarks' " open="false">
                <div id="bookmark"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="basicNode1" style="position:absolute; left:170px; bottom:30px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">
            <span id="info1" ></span>

        </div >

        <div id="basicNode2" style="position:absolute; left:170px; bottom:10px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">
            <span id="info2" ></span>

        </div >
    </div>

    <div id="search" ></div>

</div>
<div  splitter="true"  id="left"    >
    <div id="tab1">
        <div id="contenttab1">
            <div id="tocDiv"> </div>
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" title="جستجو" style="width:275px;" attachParent="true">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="top"  region="top" >

    <div id="tab1top">

        <div id="generaltools" >

            <!--Checkbox for xy coordinate-->
            <div id="checkBox"></div> <label style="position: absolute;left:680px;top:35px; " > Show/Hide Coordinates</label>
            <div id="BookmarkCheck"></div> <label style="position: absolute;left:680px;top:55px; " > Show/Hide Bookmark</label>
            <div  title="measure  "  id="mesurementID" style="position:absolute;  left:300px; top:10px;width: 200px;height: 80px;">
                <div id="measurementDiv"  locationIcon="None">  </div>
            </div>

        </div></div>
    <div id="generaltools2">



    </div>


</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The below image shows Direction widget in my web.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle ? It is obviously a simple javascript mistake but it is impossible to find out without a running example.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in above sample and i was able to see the directions widget.
I removed map parameters and layers and sample is working fine now.
I am using a single map server in the sample.

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Identify with Popup</title>


<style>
    html, body, #map {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.17/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css" />

<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css">
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/MyStyles2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.17/3.17/agsjs/css/agsjs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//js.arcgis.com/3.17"></script>
<script>

var map,toc,tb,queryTask;

var theme = "Wetland";
require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer","esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend","dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser","esri/dijit/OverviewMap"
            ,"esri/dijit/Scalebar","esri/toolbars/navigation","dijit/registry","dojo/on","esri/tasks/GeometryService","esri/SpatialReference","esri/tasks/ProjectParameters","dojo/dom","esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/layers/ImageParameters","esri/dijit/Geocoder","esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",  "esri/geometry/screenUtils","dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/query","dojo/_base/Color","esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
            ,"esri/InfoTemplate", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane","dijit/layout/BorderContainer","esri/Color","dojo/keys","esri/config","esri/sniff","esri/SnappingManager", "esri/dijit/Measurement",
            "dojo/dom-construct","dojo/dom-class","esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol","esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol","esri/tasks/IdentifyTask","esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters","esri/dijit/Popup", "dojo/_base/array","dojo/_base/connect","esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol","esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic","esri/toolbars/draw","esri/dijit/InfoWindow","esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer","dojox/charting/Chart2D", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
            "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight", "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip","dojox/charting/themes/" + theme, "dojo/dom-class","dojo/number","esri/geometry/Point","dojo/dom-style",
            "dojo/fx/Toggler","dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/RadioButton","esri/dijit/Bookmarks","esri/dijit/Directions","dojo/ready",
            "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" , "dijit/Toolbar","dijit/TitlePane",
            "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","dojox/layout/FloatingPane","dijit/form/Button" ,"dojo/fx","dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Map,Tiled,FeatureLayer,Legend, arrayUtils, parser,overviewmap,Scalebar,Navigation,registry,on,GeometryService,SpatialReference,ProjectParameters,dom,ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,ImageParameters,Geocoder,Graphic,SimpleMarkerSymbol,
                 screenUtils,domConstruct, query, Color,Search,FeatureLayer,InfoTemplate,AccordionContainer,ContentPane,BorderContainer,esriColor,Keys,esriConfig, has,SnappingManager, Measurement,construct,
                 domClass,SimpleFillSymbol,SimpleLineSymbol,IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters, Popup,arrayUtils,connect,PictureFillSymbol,CartographicLineSymbol,
                 Graphic,Draw,InfoWindow,SimpleRenderer, TabContainer,Chart2D, Pie,Highlight, MoveSlice, Tooltip,dojoxTheme, domClass,number,Point,domstyle,Toggler,CheckBox,RadioButton,Bookmark,Directions,Ready) {


            Ready(function () {
                parser.parse();
                // Close Sidebar - remove draggable Splitter
                function toggleSidebar(appLayout, contentAccordion) {
                    var panelIndex = appLayout.getIndexOfChild(contentAccordion);
                    if (panelIndex >= 0) {
                        appLayout.removeChild(contentAccordion);
                    } else {
                        appLayout.addChild(contentAccordion);
                    }
                }

//Close Sidebar - leave draggable Splitter
                function toggleSidebarWidth(appLayout, contentAccordion) {
                    var size = dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode);
                    if (size.w > 0) {
                        dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode, {w: 0});
                    } else {
                        dojo.marginBox(contentAccordion.domNode, {w: 100});
                    }
                    appLayout.resize();
                }

                dojo.ready(function () {

                    var appLayout,
                            contentAccordion,
                            accordionPane1,
                            center,


                    // create the BorderContainer and attach it to our appLayout div
                            appLayout = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({}, dojo.byId("appLayout"));

                    // create the AccordionContainer
                    contentAccordion = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "top",
                        id: "top",
                        splitter: "true",
                        minSize: "0",
                        duration: "125"
                    }, "top");


                    tab1top = new dijit.layout.TabContainer(
                            {
                                attachParent: "true",
                                title: "Draw",
                                tabPosition: "top",
                                tabStrip: "true",
                                id: "tab1top"

                            }, "tab1top");
                    contentAccordion.addChild(tab1top);
                    generaltools = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "General Tools",
                        id: "generaltools"
                    }, 'generaltools');
                    tab1top.addChild(generaltools);


                    /////


                    generaltools2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "Genera2 Tools",
                        id: "generaltools2"
                    }, 'generaltools2');
                    tab1top.addChild(generaltools2);
////

                    // add the AccordionContainer to the BorderContainer
                    appLayout.addChild(contentAccordion);

                    // create the TabContainer
                    center = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "center",
                        id: "center"

                    }, "center");
                    /// rightpane
                    rightpane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        region: "right",
                        id: "right",
                        style: "width:250px"

                    }, "rightpane");
                    appLayout.addChild(rightpane);
                    contentAccordionleft = new dojox.layout.ExpandoPane({
                        region: "left",
                        id: "left",
                        splitter: "true",
                        minSize: "0"
                    }, "left");
                    tab1 = new dijit.layout.TabContainer(
                            {
                                attachParent: "true",
                                tabPosition: "bottom",
                                tabStrip: "true",
                                id: "tab1"

                            }, "tab1");
                    contentAccordionleft.addChild(tab1);
                    appLayout.addChild(contentAccordionleft);
//                        contentAccordion.addChild(accordionPaneleft);
                    contentpanetab1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({

                        title: "legend"
                    }, "contenttab1")
                    // add the TabContainer to the BorderContainer
                    appLayout.addChild(center);

                    // calculate and set layout
                    appLayout.startup();

                    // Add button to Tab 1
                    var button1 = new dijit.form.Button({
                        id: "addremovebtn",
                        style: "position:absolute;top:20px;right:40px;height:36px;",
                        iconClass: 'AddRemove',
                        onClick: function () {
                            toggleSidebar(appLayout, contentAccordion);

                        }
                    }, "AddRemove").placeAt("center", "last");
                    domstyle.set(addremovebtn.domNode, "width", "30px");
                    domstyle.set(addremovebtn.domNode.firstChild, "display", "block");

                });


// toggler to show xy coordinate
                var toggler1 = new Toggler({
                    node: "basicNode1"
                });
                var toggler2 = new Toggler({
                    node: "basicNode2"
                });
//checkbox to check the XY coordinate
                var checkBox = new CheckBox({

                    name: "checkBox",
                    value: "agreed",
                    checked: "true",
                    style: "position: absolute;left:650px;top:35px;",

                    onChange: function () {
                        toggler1.hide(), toggler2.hide();
                        if (dijit.byId("checkBox").checked) {
                            toggler1.show();
                            toggler2.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            toggler1.hide();
                            toggler2.hide();
                        }
                    }


                }, "checkBox").startup();


//toggler to show bookmark


                var togglerbook1 = new Toggler({
                    node: "bookmarknode"
                });

//checkbox to check the XY coordinate
                var BookmarkCheck = new CheckBox({

                    name: "checkboxbook",
                    value: "agreed",
                    checked: "true",
                    style: "position: absolute;left:650px;top:55px;",

                    onChange: function () {
                        togglerbook1.hide()
                        if (dijit.byId("BookmarkCheck").checked) {
                            togglerbook1.show();


                        }
                        else {
                            togglerbook1.hide();

                        }
                    }

                }, "BookmarkCheck").startup();

                domClass.add(dom.byId('mesurementID'));

                // Use the info window instead of the popup.(For Pie Chart)

                var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(null, domConstruct.create("div"));
                infoWindow.startup();
                map = new Map("map", {logo: false});


                //For Pie Chart
                map.infoWindow.resize(275, 275);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate();
                // Flag icons are from http://twitter.com/thefella, released under creative commons.
                template.setTitle("<br>  ${District}منطقه </br>");
                template.setContent(getWindowContent);


                var popup = new Popup({
                    fillSymbol: new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                                    new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))
                }, domConstruct.create("div"));
                var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
                imageParameters.format = "jpeg";
                //var tiled = new Tiled("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ol/olbasemap/MapServer");
                var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/SuperTuesdaySample/MapServer");
                //var traffic = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/na/MapServer");

                map.addLayers([dynamicMapServiceLayer]);

                //Pie chart


                function getWindowContent(graphic) {
                    map.infoWindow.resize(275, 275);
                    // Make a tab container.
                    var tc = new TabContainer({
                        style: "width:100%;height:100%;"
                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));

                    // Display attribute information.
                    var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "Details",
                        content: "سstat" +
                        graphic.attributes.District + "<br>جمعیت کل  : " +
                        graphic.attributes.TotalEdu + "<br>OBJECTID: " +
                        graphic.attributes.OBJECTID


                    });


                    var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "Pie Chart"
                    });
                    tc.addChild(cp1);
                    tc.addChild(cp2);

                    // Create the chart that will display in the second tab.
                    var c = domConstruct.create("div", {
                        id: "demoChart"
                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));
                    var chart = new Chart2D(c);
                    domClass.add(chart, "chart");

                    // Apply a color theme to the chart.
                    chart.setTheme(dojoxTheme);
                    chart.addPlot("default", {
                        type: "Pie",
                        radius: 70,
                        htmlLabels: true
                    });
                    tc.watch("selectedChildWidget", function (name, oldVal, newVal) {
                        if (newVal.title === "Pie Chart") {
                            chart.resize(180, 180);
                        }
                    });

                    // Calculate percent male/female.
                    var total = graphic.attributes.TotalEdu;
                    var educatedman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_EducatedMan / total * 100, 2);
                    var educatedwoman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_EducatedWoman / total * 100, 2);
                    var uneducatedman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_UnEducatedMan / total * 100, 2);
                    var uneducatewodman = number.round(graphic.attributes.Sum_UnEducatedWoman / total * 100, 2);
                    chart.addSeries("PopulationSplit", [{
                        y: educatedman,
                        tooltip: "A",
//                            text: "educatedman"
                    }, {
                        y: educatedwoman,
                        tooltip: "b",
//                            text: "educatedwoman"
                    },
                        {
                            y: uneducatedman,
                            tooltip: "c",
//                                text:"uneducatedman"
                        },
                        {
                            y: uneducatewodman,
                            tooltip: "d",
//                                text: "uneducatewodman"
                        }
                    ]);
                    //highlight the chart and display tooltips when you mouse over a slice.
                    new Highlight(chart, "default");
                    new Tooltip(chart, "default");
                    new MoveSlice(chart, "default");

                    cp2.set("content", chart.node);
                    return tc.domNode;
                }

                var directions = new Directions({
                    map: map,
                    routeTaskUrl: "http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/mobile/traffic_wgs2/NAServer/Route"


                },"dir");
                directions.startup();
            });
        });

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

</script>
</head>

<body  class="claro" role="main">
<div id="appLayout"  style="width:100%; height:100%;" >

</div>
<div id="rightpane">

    <div id="dir"></div>
</div>
<div id="center">

    <div id="map" style="background-color:#F7F3E7;width:100%;height:100% ">
        <div id="bookmarknode" style="position:absolute; right:120px; top:20px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">


            <div id="bookmarks-pane"
                 data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane"
                 data-dojo-props="title:'Bookmarks' " open="false">
                <div id="bookmark"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="basicNode1" style="position:absolute; left:170px; bottom:30px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">
            <span id="info1" ></span>

        </div >

        <div id="basicNode2" style="position:absolute; left:170px; bottom:10px; color:#000; z-index:50;background-color:navajowhite ">
            <span id="info2" ></span>

        </div >
    </div>

    <div id="search" ></div>

</div>
<div  splitter="true"  id="left"    >
    <div id="tab1">
        <div id="contenttab1">
            <div id="tocDiv"> </div>
        </div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" title="جستجو" style="width:275px;" attachParent="true">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="top"  region="top" >

    <div id="tab1top">

        <div id="generaltools" >

            <!--Checkbox for xy coordinate-->
            <div id="checkBox"></div> <label style="position: absolute;left:680px;top:35px; " > Show/Hide Coordinates</label>
            <div id="BookmarkCheck"></div> <label style="position: absolute;left:680px;top:55px; " > Show/Hide Bookmark</label>
            <div  title="measure  "  id="mesurementID" style="position:absolute;  left:300px; top:10px;width: 200px;height: 80px;">
                <div id="measurementDiv"  locationIcon="None">  </div>
            </div>

        </div></div>
    <div id="generaltools2">



    </div>


</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
</pre>
```

Here is the screen shot of what i am seeing.
[image]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. But map parameters and layers are the core of my webgis

Comment: I am not able to access the layers. If you can share global urls of your layers then i can check and let you know the reason behind the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just cleaned up the mess that you name to be your require ;-)

Cleaned out sone doubles and add the missing pieces:

```
require([
     "agsjs/dijit/TOC",
     "esri/Color",
     "esri/config",
     "esri/dijit/Bookmarks",
     "esri/dijit/Directions",
     "esri/dijit/Geocoder",
     "esri/dijit/InfoWindow",
     "esri/dijit/Legend",
     "esri/dijit/Measurement",
     "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
     "esri/dijit/Popup", 
     "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
     "esri/dijit/Search",
     "esri/geometry/Point",
     "esri/geometry/screenUtils",
     "esri/graphic",
     "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
     "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
     "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
     "esri/layers/ImageParameters",
     "esri/InfoTemplate",
     "esri/map",
     "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
     "esri/SnappingManager",
     "esri/sniff",
     "esri/SpatialReference",
     "esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
     "esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
     "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
     "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
     "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
     "esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters",
     "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters",
     "esri/toolbars/draw",
     "esri/toolbars/navigation",

     "dojo/_base/array",
     "dojo/_base/connect",
     "dojo/_base/Color",
     "dojo/dom",
     "dojo/dom-class",
     "dojo/dom-construct",
     "dojo/dom-style",
     "dojo/fx",
     "dojo/fx/Toggler",
     "dojo/keys",
     "dojo/number",
     "dojo/on",
     "dojo/parser",
     "dojo/query",
     "dojo/ready",

     "dijit/form/Button" ,
     "dijit/form/CheckBox", 
     "dijit/form/RadioButton",
     "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
     "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
     "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
     "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
     "dijit/registry",
     "dijit/TitlePane",
     "dijit/Toolbar",

     "dojox/charting/Chart2D",
     "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
     "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight",
     "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
     "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
     "dojox/charting/themes/" + theme,
     "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" , 
     "dojox/layout/FloatingPane",
     "dojo/domReady!"
     ],
    function(   TOC,
                esriColor, 
                esriConfig,
                Bookmark,
                Directions,
                Geocoder,
                InfoWindow,
                Legend,
                Measurement,
                overviewmap,
                Popup,
                Scalebar,
                Search,
                Point,
                screenUtils,
                Graphic,
                Tiled,
                ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
                FeatureLayer,
                ImageParameters,
                InfoTemplate,
                Map,
                SimpleRenderer,
                SnappingManager,
                has,
                SpatialReference,
                CartographicLineSymbol,
                PictureFillSymbol,
                SimpleMarkerSymbol,
                SimpleFillSymbol,
                SimpleLineSymbol,
                GeometryService,
                IdentifyTask,
                IdentifyParameters,
                ProjectParameters,
                Draw,
                Navigation,
                arrayUtils,
                connect,
                Color, //double
                dom,
                domClass,
                domConstruct,
                domstyle,
                fx, //forgotten
                Toggler,
                Keys,
                number,
                on,
                parser,
                query,
                Ready,

                Button, // forgotten
                CheckBox,
                RadioButton,
                AccordionContainer,
                BorderContainer,
                ContentPane,
                TabContainer,
                registry,
                TitlePane, // forgotten
                Toolbar, // forgotten

                Chart2D, 
                Pie,
                Highlight, 
                MoveSlice, 
                Tooltip,
                dojoxTheme,
                ExpandoPane, // forgotten
                FloatingPane // forgotten
                ) {
```